# Raycast point returns multiple values without moving

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting

```
RaycastHit hit;
    if(Physics.Raycast(character.cam.transform.position, character.cam.lookDir, out hit)){
        Debug.Log(hit.point);
    }
```

this returns 3 to 4 different values, one a frame, without moving or rotating the camera

Comment: what are you expecting it to do?

Comment: give only a single answer from a single ray

Comment: By "3 to 4 different values", what kind of value do you mean? (i.e. numbers, objects, arrays) In Unity3D's documentation (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit.html) the `point` member of `RaycastHit` is a single `Vector3`, so the 3 values you see may be its components.

Comment: 3 or 4 Vector3 .

Answer (score -1):

It is probably hitting multiple targets.

Comment: i am not using raycastAll, im using raycast

Comment: and there's only a floor in the scene

Comment: Please post a picture of what values are being Logged

Comment: How do i do that, what website and software?

Comment: Snipping tool, or printscreen and then crop

Comment: I dont understand your directions

Comment: Actually i got it, its on the way, I am not near my computer

Comment: what website do i post the images on?